# routes not working after upgrade to 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

I upgraded from SS 3.0 to 3.1 today and since updating, the system does not seem to be detecting my routes.yml file in my extensions' _config folders. Here is an example of my myextension/_config/routes.yml file:

```
---
Name: pusherroutes
After: 
  - '#rootroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    # handle old 2.4 style urls
    'pusher/$Action': 'PusherController'
```

I have also set my allowed_actions static to whitelist my controller actions:

```
class PusherController extends Controller {
    public static $allowed_actions = array (
    'ChatAuth',
    'SendMessage',
    'NotifyAuth'
    );
}
```

When I navigate to mysite.com/pusher/SendMessage the system is no longer directing me to the action method on the controller. The response being returned in my network tab is the Silverstripe getting started page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `$Action` parameter is being matched twice. When the initial `pusher/$Action` route is matched, the first two parts of the URL are consumed as part of the match. Control is then passed to your `PusherController` object. This then tries to match the URL to an action again, but since there is no URL left to parse, it decides there is no action present, so it routes to the `index` action, which in turn displays the getting started info.

To fix this, just use:

```
Director:
  rules:
    'pusher': 'PusherController'
```

and rely on the action matching being done when control is handed to `PusherController`.